# Why can we assign a literal integer of 32 bit to a variable of type short without casting?

Tags: c#

In my understanding literal integers belong to `System.Int32` by default. If so why can we assign a literal integer of type `System.Int32` to `short x` without casting?

```
short x = 1;//compilable
```

Why don't we need to use casting as follows?

```
short x = (short)1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the specification allows for that in section 6.1.9:

> A constant expression of type `int` can be converted to `sbyte`, `byte`,
>   `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the constant
>   expression is within the range of the destination type.

The `1` is indeed a constant expression of type `int` because (section 2.4.4.2, "Integer literals"):

> The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.

Comment: Added the section number for clarity - hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Is there C# specification document in PDF format rather than MS-Word format? I have no Word installed. :-)

Comment: @CodeMocker: Open source office suites such as OpenOffice and LibreOffice can open it, you don't need Word. Google Docs or similar online services can also do it.